# Delete duplicates in a List of int arrays

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

having a List of int arrays like:

```
List<int[]> intArrList = new List<int[]>();
intArrList.Add(new int[3] { 0, 0, 0 });
intArrList.Add(new int[5] { 20, 30, 10, 4, 6 });  //this
intArrList.Add(new int[3] { 1, 2, 5 });
intArrList.Add(new int[5] { 20, 30, 10, 4, 6 });  //this
intArrList.Add(new int[3] { 12, 22, 54 });
intArrList.Add(new int[5] { 1, 2, 6, 7, 8 });
intArrList.Add(new int[4] { 0, 0, 0, 0 });
```

How would you remove duplicates (by duplicate I mean element of list has same length and same numbers).

On the example I would remove element `{ 20, 30, 10, 4, 6 }` because it is found twice

I was thinking on sorting the list by element size, then loop each element against rest but I am not sure how to do that.

Other question would be, if using other structure like a Hash would be better... If so how to use it?

Comment: does it matter if they are in the same order and if the numbers are the same but one list has one of the numbers repeated?

Comment: well, Actually It matters as long as they have same length, for instance `{1,2,3,4} is equal as {2,3,4,1}`

Comment: Be careful ! A robust and performant answer to this question is non-trivial to implement, whilst a specious and/or slow solution to this problem is trivial to implement

Comment: @J.P so no answer to this question satisfy you? If so, why? Too slow, too ugly?

Comment: @J.P HashSet<int> , notice the "set" in the name. would be MUCH more efficient, but you it would not be feasible to solve the problem as-is. It would be impossible to store the data. In a set, order(ing) does not make sense and there are no duplicates. Hashet also has a method called SetEquals which is much more efficient than the comparisons in the solutions already present. However, duplicates and ordering are at the heart of the problem as-is., without these requirements, it is trivial. A custom class or Dictionary<int,int> might be feasible. I will try tomorrow. Now I sleep :)

Comment: @Evk I think it's the added requirement: Other question would be, if using other structure like a Hash would be better... If so how to use it?

Comment: @J.P SortedList maybe? O(n) insertion not too bad. Itepends on the number of lists though. I would assume a sane person that would have this problem in real life would keep the lists sorted and ready for processing at least :) Now I really go sleep!

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea but that part was added by original author years ago. J.P only added couple of tags and bounty (as seen from post question history).

Comment: @Evk You are right, my bad for misreading the history. Perhaps OP felt that the answers could be improved? In which case I upvoted and second your comment to provide more details into what he really wants to achieve with the bounty :)

Comment: @Evk Sorry I wanted to start a bounty for this question for this reason **This question has not received enough attention.** but unfortunately I forgot to change the bounty reason option and so it strated with it's default option. Actually all the answers are fairly fine and correct. I don't know if there is a way to edit the bounty reason so that it is not misleading.

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea Sorry I wanted to start a bounty for this question for this reason **This question has not received enough attention.** but unfortunately I forgot to change the bounty reason option and so it strated with it's default option. Actually all the answers are fairly fine and correct. I don't know if there is a way to edit the bounty reason so that it is not misleading.

Comment: @J.P to be honest I don't see what it changes :) Question has 4 upvoted answers, accepted answer, so I don't see why it did not receive enough attention.

Comment: @J.P I do think there are more efficient answers , at least in performance, using a custom data structure and perhaps a bit different approach, but that would be too "involved", it would be quite some effort. For simple cases (homework I presume) any of them would work

Comment: @J.P In addition to what was already mentioned the bounty should **not** change the original intend of the question. All the existing answers already answer the question perfectly. When you feel some answer might be missing, you may have another question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534304(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var result = intArrList.GroupBy(c => String.Join(",", c))
                       .Select(c => c.First().ToList()).ToList();
```

The result:

> {0, 0, 0}
>
> {20, 30, 10, 4, 6}
>
> {1, 2, 5}
>
> {12, 22, 54}
>
> {1, 2, 6, 7, 8}
>
> {0, 0, 0, 0}

**EDIT**: If you want to consider `{1,2,3,4}` be equal to `{2,3,4,1}` you need to use `OrderBy` like this:

```
var result = intArrList.GroupBy(p => string.Join(", ", p.OrderBy(c => c)))
                       .Select(c => c.First().ToList()).ToList();
```

**EDIT2**: To help understanding how the LINQ `GroupBy` solution works consider the following method:

```
public List<int[]> FindDistinctWithoutLinq(List<int[]> lst)
{
    var dic = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
    foreach (var item in lst)
    {
        string key = string.Join(",", item.OrderBy(c=>c));

        if (!dic.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            dic.Add(key, item);
        }
    }

    return dic.Values.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Also you can implement an `EqualityComparer` class and use it in `Distinct` method of LINQ. But I think it would be more simple by using `GroupBy` for this purpose

Comment: will `GropuBy` consider `{1,2,3,4}` be equal to `{2,3,4,1}` ?

Comment: You can use order by on c before you Group it, that way it will be equal

Comment: I have something like this in mind: var result = intArrList.GroupBy(p => string.Join(", ", p.OrderBy(c => c))).Select(c => c.First().ToList()).ToList();

Comment: @cMinor...I have provided a method for you to help understanding how LINQ-based solution works. See the updated answer again.

Comment: First suggestion doesn't return the same type as the input List. You have to many ToList(). Shouldn't it be: var result = intArrList.GroupBy(c => String.Join(",", c))
                       .Select(c => c.First()).ToList();

Answer (score 12):

You can define your own implementation of `IEqualityComparer` and use it together with `IEnumerable.Distinct`:

```
class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]> 
{
    public int GetHashCode(int[] instance) { return 0; } // TODO: better HashCode for arrays
    public bool Equals(int[] instance, int[] other)
    {
        if (other == null || instance == null || instance.Length != other.Length) return false;

        return instance.SequenceEqual(other);
    }
}
```

Now write this to get only distinct values for your list:

```
var result = intArrList.Distinct(new MyComparer());
```

However if you want different permutations also you should implement your comparer this way:

```
public bool Equals(int[] instance, int[] other)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(instance, other)) return true; // this will return true when both arrays are NULL
    if (other == null || instance == null) return false;
    return instance.All(x => other.Contains(x)) && other.All(x => instance.Contains(x));
}
```

EDIT: For a better `GetashCode`-implementation you may have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3404820/2528063) as also suggested in @Mick´s answer.

Comment: Will this solution consider `{1,2,3,4`} be equal to `{2,3,4,1}` as OP wants ?

Comment: Sure, it should as you can see in the second `Equals`-implementation. Or do I miss anything?

Answer (score 8):

Well lifting code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404715/c-sharp-hashcode-for-array-of-ints) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713341/comparing-arrays-in-c-sharp).  A more generic implementation of GetHashCode would make this more generic, however I believe the implementation below is the most robust

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int[]> intArrList = new List<int[]>();
        intArrList.Add(new int[3] { 0, 0, 0 });
        intArrList.Add(new int[5] { 20, 30, 10, 4, 6 });  //this
        intArrList.Add(new int[3] { 1, 2, 5 });
        intArrList.Add(new int[5] { 20, 30, 10, 4, 6 });  //this
        intArrList.Add(new int[3] { 12, 22, 54 });
        intArrList.Add(new int[5] { 1, 2, 6, 7, 8 });
        intArrList.Add(new int[4] { 0, 0, 0, 0 });

        var test = intArrList.Distinct(new IntArrayEqualityComparer());
        Console.WriteLine(test.Count());
        Console.WriteLine(intArrList.Count());
    }

    public class IntArrayEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]>
    {
        public bool Equals(int[] x, int[] y)
        {
            return ArraysEqual(x, y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(int[] obj)
        {
            int hc = obj.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < obj.Length; ++i)
            {
                hc = unchecked(hc * 17 + obj[i]);
            }
            return hc;
        }

        static bool ArraysEqual<T>(T[] a1, T[] a2)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(a1, a2))
                return true;

            if (a1 == null || a2 == null)
                return false;

            if (a1.Length != a2.Length)
                return false;

            EqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
            for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!comparer.Equals(a1[i], a2[i])) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** a Generic implementation of IEqualityComparer for an arrays of any type:-

```
public class ArrayEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T[]>
{
    public bool Equals(T[] x, T[] y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;

        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        if (x.Length != y.Length)
            return false;

        EqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!comparer.Equals(x[i], y[i])) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T[] obj)
    {
        int hc = obj.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.Length; ++i)
        {
            hc = unchecked(hc * 17 + obj[i].GetHashCode());
        }
        return hc;
    }
}
```

**Edit2**: If ordering of the integers within the arrays doesn't matter I would

```
var test = intArrList.Select(a => a.OrderBy(e => e).ToArray()).Distinct(comparer).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice `HashCode`-implementation.

Comment: I don't take credit for it, as stated it is from one of the links.  Good hashcode implementation is a pretty tricky thing.  An average Hashcode  implementation will work 99.99999% of the time and bite you fairly squarely in the ass 0.00001% of the time.

Comment: That´s why I concentrated my affords in the answer on the useful stuff :). Good answer though, upvoted.

Comment: Return false for x!= null and y == null, fair enough. Anyway, I think this solution is the most efficient one that also scales better for bigger lists (in terms of memory) compared to the accepted answer. Trying to come up with my own answer, but sadly set theory no like duplicates. One question though: do you think it would be better to GroupBy(l => l.Count) and then SelectMany.Distinct and only sort the lists  where comparisons are needed i.e. group.Count>1? My intuition would say that this would lead to less comparisons, but maybe this is something that is already optimized by the CLR?

Comment: I mean use Distinct within the group(same counts) and SelectMany afterwards. Of course I am most likely entirely wrong. I know GroupBy is constly too, it just seems to me to be worth it to reduce the cost of sorting all lists and calling distinct on the whole list.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<int[]> CopyString1 = new List<int[]>();
CopyString1.AddRange(intArrList);
List<int[]> CopyString2 = new List<int[]>();
CopyString2.AddRange(intArrList);
for (int i = 0; i < CopyString2.Count(); i++)
{
    for (int j = i; j < CopyString1.Count(); j++)
    {
        if (i != j && CopyString2[i].Count() == CopyString1[j].Count())
        {
            var cnt = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < CopyString2[i].Count(); k++)
            {
                if (CopyString2[i][k] == CopyString1[j][k])
                    cnt++;
                else
                    break;
            }
            if (cnt == CopyString2[i].Count())
                intArrList.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this implementation?  Surely the `RemoveAt(i)` is incorrect after the first removal?  As you're iterating `i` up through the list, after you have removed the first entry, the elements in `CopyString1` and `intArrList` are no longer aligned.

Answer (score 3):

Perf comparison of @S.Akbari's and @Mick's solutions using BenchmarkDotNet

**EDIT:**

SAkbari_FindDistinctWithoutLinq has redundant call to ContainsKey, so i added impoved and faster version: SAkbari_FindDistinctWithoutLinq2

```
                           Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
--------------------------------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|
  SAkbari_FindDistinctWithoutLinq | 4.021 us | 0.0723 us | 0.0676 us |
 SAkbari_FindDistinctWithoutLinq2 | 3.930 us | 0.0529 us | 0.0495 us |
         SAkbari_FindDistinctLinq | 5.597 us | 0.0264 us | 0.0234 us |
            Mick_UsingGetHashCode | 6.339 us | 0.0265 us | 0.0248 us |
```

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.13, OS=Windows 10 Redstone 3 [1709, Fall Creators Update] (10.0.16299.248)
Intel Core i7-7700 CPU 3.60GHz (Kaby Lake), 1 CPU, 8 logical cores and 4 physical cores
Frequency=3515625 Hz, Resolution=284.4444 ns, Timer=TSC
.NET Core SDK=2.1.100
  [Host]     : .NET Core 2.0.5 (CoreCLR 4.6.26020.03, CoreFX 4.6.26018.01), 64bit RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 2.0.5 (CoreCLR 4.6.26020.03, CoreFX 4.6.26018.01), 64bit RyuJIT
```

Benchmark:

```
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        List<int[]> intArrList = new List<int[]>
        {
            new int[] { 0, 0, 0 },
            new int[] { 20, 30, 10, 4, 6 },  //this
            new int[] { 1, 2, 5 },
            new int[] { 20, 30, 10, 4, 6 },  //this
            new int[] { 12, 22, 54 },
            new int[] { 1, 2, 6, 7, 8 },
            new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
        };

        [Benchmark]
        public List<int[]> SAkbari_FindDistinctWithoutLinq() => FindDistinctWithoutLinq(intArrList);

        [Benchmark]
        public List<int[]> SAkbari_FindDistinctWithoutLinq2() => FindDistinctWithoutLinq2(intArrList);

        [Benchmark]
        public List<int[]> SAkbari_FindDistinctLinq() => FindDistinctLinq(intArrList);

        [Benchmark]
        public List<int[]> Mick_UsingGetHashCode() => FindDistinctLinq(intArrList);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<Program>();
        }

        public static List<int[]> FindDistinctWithoutLinq(List<int[]> lst)
        {
            var dic = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
            foreach (var item in lst)
            {
                string key = string.Join(",", item.OrderBy(c => c));

                if (!dic.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    dic.Add(key, item);
                }
            }

            return dic.Values.ToList();
        }

        public static List<int[]> FindDistinctWithoutLinq2(List<int[]> lst)
        {
            var dic = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();

            foreach (var item in lst)
                dic.TryAdd(string.Join(",", item.OrderBy(c => c)), item);

            return dic.Values.ToList();
        }

        public static List<int[]> FindDistinctLinq(List<int[]> lst)
        {
            return lst.GroupBy(p => string.Join(", ", p.OrderBy(c => c)))
                       .Select(c => c.First().ToArray()).ToList();
        }

        public static List<int[]> UsingGetHashCode(List<int[]> lst)
        {
            return lst.Select(a => a.OrderBy(e => e).ToArray()).Distinct(new IntArrayEqualityComparer()).ToList();
        }
    }

    public class IntArrayEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]>
    {
        public bool Equals(int[] x, int[] y)
        {
            return ArraysEqual(x, y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(int[] obj)
        {
            int hc = obj.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < obj.Length; ++i)
            {
                hc = unchecked(hc * 17 + obj[i]);
            }
            return hc;
        }

        static bool ArraysEqual<T>(T[] a1, T[] a2)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(a1, a2))
                return true;

            if (a1 == null || a2 == null)
                return false;

            if (a1.Length != a2.Length)
                return false;

            EqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
            for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!comparer.Equals(a1[i], a2[i])) return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Input list;

```
List<List<int>> initList = new List<List<int>>();
initList.Add(new List<int>{ 0, 0, 0 });
initList.Add(new List<int>{ 20, 30, 10, 4, 6 });  //this
initList.Add(new List<int> { 1, 2, 5 });
initList.Add(new List<int> { 20, 30, 10, 4, 6 });  //this
initList.Add(new List<int> { 12, 22, 54 });
initList.Add(new List<int> { 1, 2, 6, 7, 8 });
initList.Add(new List<int> { 0, 0, 0, 0 });
```

You can create a result list, and before adding elements you can check if it is already added. I simply compared the list counts and used `p.Except(item).Any()` call to check if the list contains that element or not.

```
List<List<int>> returnList = new List<List<int>>();

foreach (var item in initList)
{
    if (returnList.Where(p => !p.Except(item).Any() && !item.Except(p).Any()
                             && p.Count() == item.Count() ).Count() == 0)
    returnList.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a HashSet.
HashSet is a collection used for guarantee uniqueness and you can compare items on collection, Intersect, Union. etc.

Pros: No duplicates, easy to manipulate groups of data, more efficient
Cons: You can't get a specific item in the collection, for example: list[0] doesn't work for HashSets. You can only Enumerating the items. e.g. foreach

Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HashSet<HashSet<int>> intArrList = new HashSet<HashSet<int>>(new HashSetIntComparer());
            intArrList.Add(new HashSet<int>(3) { 0, 0, 0 });
            intArrList.Add(new HashSet<int>(5) { 20, 30, 10, 4, 6 });  //this
            intArrList.Add(new HashSet<int>(3) { 1, 2, 5 });
            intArrList.Add(new HashSet<int>(5) { 20, 30, 10, 4, 6 });  //this
            intArrList.Add(new HashSet<int>(3) { 12, 22, 54 });
            intArrList.Add(new HashSet<int>(5) { 1, 2, 6, 7, 8 });
            intArrList.Add(new HashSet<int>(4) { 0, 0, 0, 0 });

            // Checking the output
            foreach (var item in intArrList)
            {
                foreach (var subHasSet in item)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} ", subHasSet);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }            

            Console.Read();
        }

        private class HashSetIntComparer : IEqualityComparer<HashSet<int>>
        {
            public bool Equals(HashSet<int> x, HashSet<int> y)
            {
                // SetEquals does't set anything. It's a method for compare the contents of the HashSet. 
                // Such a poor name from .Net
                return x.SetEquals(y);
            }

            public int GetHashCode(HashSet<int> obj)
            {
                //TODO: implemente a better HashCode
                return base.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
    }
}


Output:
0
20 30 10 4 6
1 2 5
12 22 54
1 2 6 7 8
```

> Note: Since 0 is repeated several times, HashSet considers the 0 only
>   once. If you need diferentiate between 0 0 0 0 and 0 0 0 then you can
>   replace `HashSet<HashSet<int>> for HashSet<List<int>>` and implement
>   a Comparer to the List instead.

You can use this link to learn how to compare a list:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2ff3016c-bd61-4fec-8f8c-7b6c070123fa/c-compare-two-lists-of-objects?forum=csharplanguage

If you want to learn more about Collections and DataTypes this course is a perfect place to learn it: 
https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=csharp-collections&author=simon-robinson&name=csharp-collections-fundamentals-m9-sets&clip=1&mode=live

Answer (score 1):

Using MoreLINQ this can be very simple with DistinctBy.

```
var result = intArrList.DistinctBy(x => string.Join(",", x));
```

Similar to the GroupBy answer if you want distinction to be irrespective of order just order in the join.

```
var result = intArrList.DistinctBy(x => string.Join(",", x.OrderBy(y => y)));
```

**EDIT**: This is how it's implemented

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
            Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
        {
            if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keySelector));

            return _(); IEnumerable<TSource> _()
            {
                var knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
                foreach (var element in source)
                {
                    if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
                        yield return element;
                }
            }
        }
```

So you if you don't need MoreLINQ for anything else you can just use a method like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<int[]> GetUniqueArrays(IEnumerable<int[]> source)
    {
        var knownKeys = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var element in source)
        {
            if (knownKeys.Add(string.Join(",", element)))
                yield return element;
        }
    }
```