# How to check for distinct array stored in a list

Tags: c#, arrays, distinct

How do would you get all the *distinct* `int[]` arrays in a list?

**Example:**

```
List<int[]> list = new List<int[]>() {
  new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
  new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
  new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 4 },
};
```

I want to return *distinct* arrays from list assuming the array is sorted.

Comment: Well, first you would need a way of comparing if one array is distinct from another array. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I know that there is a list.Distinct() method in C# but I don't know if it applies to arrays as well. Would this just have to be done manually?

Comment: @newuser no, `Distinct` will not work on arrays, but it is easy to check.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to see if there was a faster way to do so.

Comment: Write a method that accepts two arrays as arguments, and returns a bool for whether they are distinct or not.

Comment: @RyanWilson Checking sum and length won't work. {2, 3} and {1, 4} will be equal in this logic. But they're different. I guess it's required to write a custom compare method for comparing 2 arrays and storing them accordingly.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of: [delete-duplicates-in-a-list-of-int-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850167/delete-duplicates-in-a-list-of-int-arrays)

Comment: @Jasen I think the comment specifies that each array will be sorted: `// return distinct arrays from list assuming the array is sorted`

Comment: @RyanWilson +1, my habit of ignoring code comments ;)

Comment: @Jasen No worries. :P

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete duplicates in a List of int arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850167/delete-duplicates-in-a-list-of-int-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

When working with *distinct* we should come to terms how to *compare* items (by *default* .net compares *references*, and that's why `new[] {1, 2, 3} != new int[] {1, 2, 3}` since arrays' don't share the same reference).

We can do it while implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>` for this, e.g.

```
public sealed class EnumerableEqualityComparer<T> 
  : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> {
  
  public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T>? x, IEnumerable<T>? y) {
    if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
      return true;
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, x) || ReferenceEquals(null, y))
      return false;

    return x.SequenceEqual(y);
  }

  public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj) {
    if (obj is null)
      return -1;

    if (obj is ICollection<T> c)
      return c.Count;

    // Count() without restriction - Take(10) - can be expensive
    return obj.Take(10).Count();
  }
}
```

and then use it within `Distinct`:

```
var result = list
  .Distinct(new EnumerableEqualityComparer<int>())
  .ToList(); // let's have a list of the distinct arrays
```