# How to use System.HashCode.Combine with more than 8 values?

Tags: c#, hashcode, gethashcode

.NET Standard 2.1 / .NET Core 3 [introduce](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14354) [`System.HashCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode) to quickly combine fields and values to a hash code without having to care about the underlying implementation.

However, it only provides `Combine` method overloads for up to 8 values. What do I do if I have a class with 9 values (3x3 matrix) or even 16 values (4x4 matrix)?

Should I simply add together the results of two `Combine` calls, passing as many values as possible in each?

```cs
public override int GetHashCode()
    => HashCode.Combine(M11, M12, M13, M21, M22, M23, M31, M32) + HashCode.Combine(M33);
```

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/HashCode.cs), I cannot completely argue if this may have implications I don't know of.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As stated in the [`System.HashCode` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode), adding together hashes returned by successive `HashCode.Combine` calls is **NOT** the solution.

While the static `HashCode.Combine` method overloads only allow up to 8 values, these are just convenience methods - to combine more, instantiate the `HashCode` class itself and use it as follows:

```cs
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    HashCode hash = new();
    hash.Add(M11);
    hash.Add(M12);
    hash.Add(M13);
    hash.Add(M21);
    hash.Add(M22);
    hash.Add(M23);
    hash.Add(M31);
    hash.Add(M32);
    hash.Add(M33);
    return hash.ToHashCode();
}
```

<s>It does make me wonder why there is no `HashCode` constructor accepting a `params object[] values` so you could do all that in one line, but there are probably reasons I didn't think of this quickly.</s> *(S. the comments why such an overload does not exist.)*

Comment: It might have something to do with allocating an array, which *can* be a performance drag. Since .NET Core is more performance oriented, I would think that that's the reason.

Comment: Not only array allocation but also boxing of every value type. Horribly inefficient.

Comment: It neither does boxing nor array allocation

Comment: @Vlad Why not? Surely it has to do with performance considerations..

Comment: I meant that using `HashCode.Add` method doesn't lead to boxing or array allocation

Comment: @Vlad I think the concerns about boxing and array allocation were made about a constructor accepting a `params object[] values` which absence I mentioned in my answer, not the calls to `HashCode.Add`.